# Lightning Component to show related lists(Contacts and Opportunity) of Account using toggleclass

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Now it is working on single click all accounts are opening, but I need to open one account at a time.

Component :

```
<aura:attribute name="Accounts" type="Account[]"/> 
<aura:attribute name="page" type="integer" description="using for store page Number"/>
<aura:attribute name="pages" type="integer" description="using for store All Pages page Number"/>
<aura:attribute name="total" type="integer" description="total records count store "/>

    <p class="slds-text-title_caps">
        Account
    </p>
    <div class="slds-p-around--large"   >
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.Accounts}" var="account" aura:id="accID"  >

            <div class="slds-page-header" style="cursor: pointer;"  data-record="{!idx}" onclick="{!c.sectionOne}" >

                <section class="slds-clearfix" >

                    <div class="slds-float--left ">
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-show" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:add" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates add"/>
                        <lightning:icon class="slds-hide" aura:id="articleOne" iconName="utility:dash" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates dash"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-m-left--large" ><ui:outputText aura:id="Id" value="{!account.Name}"  />
                        </div>

                </section>
            </div>


            <div class="slds-hide slds-p-around--medium" aura:id="articleOne"  >
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal"
                       role="grid">  
                    <thead >
                        <tr>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Account name
                            </th>
                           <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Contact Name
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Phone
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Mailing City
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Mailing Country
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Contact ID
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>     
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!account.Contacts}" var="con"  >

                           <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Name">
                                    {!account.Name}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="accName">
                                    {!con.Name}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="prName">
                                    {!con.Phone}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!con.MailingCity}
                                </td>   
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!con.MailingCountry }
                                </td> 
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!con.Id}
                                </td> 

                            </tr>
                         </aura:iteration>           
                    </tbody>              
                </table>      
            </div> 
            <div class="slds-hide slds-p-around--medium" aura:id="articleOne">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal"
                       role="grid">  
                    <thead >
                        <tr>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Account name
                            </th>
                           <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Opportunity Name
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                StageName
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                CloseDate
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Probability 
                            </th>
                            <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-cell-wrap" scope="col">
                                Opportunity ID
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>     
                    <tbody>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!account.Opportunities}" var="opp">

                           <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="Name">
                                    {!account.Name}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="accName">
                                    {!opp.Name}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="prName">
                                    {!opp.StageName}
                                </td>
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!opp.CloseDate}
                                </td>   
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!opp.Probability}
                                </td> 
                                <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-wrap" data-label="manuName">
                                    {!opp.Id}
                                </td> 

                            </tr>
                         </aura:iteration>           
                    </tbody>              
                </table>      
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>            
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="slds-card__footer">

        <!-- LAYOUT GRID -->
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
        <lightning:button disabled="{!v.page == 1}" variant="brand" label="Previous Page" onclick="{! c.navigate }" />            
            <lightning:button disabled="{!v.page == v.pages}" aura:id="previousPage" variant="brand" label="Next Page" onclick="{! c.navigate }" />
        </div>

        <p class="slds-align_absolute-center">{!v.total} Accounts • page {!v.page} / {!v.pages}</p>
        <ui:inputSelect aura:id="recordSize" label="Display Record Per Page: " change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="10" label="10" value="true"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="20" label="20"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="40" label="40"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="60" label="60"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="80" label="80"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="100" label="100"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="120" label="120"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="140" label="140"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="160" label="160"/>

        </ui:inputSelect>

      <!-- / LAYOUT GRID -->
    </footer>
    <!-- / FOOTER -->
```

Controller :

```
({
   doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on the component load first time     
      // get the page Number if it's not define, take 1 as default
      var page = component.get("v.page") || 1;
      // get the select option (drop-down) values.   
      var recordToDisply = component.find("recordSize").get("v.value");
      // call the helper function   
      helper.getAccounts(component, page, recordToDisply);

   },

   navigate: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on click on the previous page button  
      var page = component.get("v.page") || 1;
      // get the previous button label  
      var direction = event.getSource().get("v.label");
      // get the select option (drop-down) values.  
      var recordToDisply = component.find("recordSize").get("v.value");
      // set the current page,(using ternary operator.)  
      page = direction === "Previous Page" ? (page - 1) : (page + 1);
      // call the helper function
      helper.getAccounts(component, page, recordToDisply);

   },

   onSelectChange: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on the select option change,   
      var page = 1
      var recordToDisply = component.find("recordSize").get("v.value");
      helper.getAccounts(component, page, recordToDisply);
   },



    sectionOne: function(component, event, helper) {
       helper.helperFun(component,event,'articleOne');
    },


})
```

Helper:

```
({ 
   getAccounts: function(component, page, recordToDisply) {

      var action = component.get("c.fetchAccount");
      action.setParams({
         "pageNumber": page,
         "recordToDisply": recordToDisply


      });
      action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
         var result = a.getReturnValue();
         console.log('result ---->' + JSON.stringify(result));
         component.set("v.Accounts", result.accounts);
         component.set("v.page", result.page);
         component.set("v.total", result.total);
         component.set("v.pages", Math.ceil(result.total / recordToDisply));


      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },

    helperFun : function(component,event,articleOne) {

      //var accValue = component.find("accID").get("v.value");
        //console.log(component.find("accID").get("v.value"));
      var acc = component.find(articleOne);
            for(var cmp in acc) {
            $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-hide');  
            $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-show');  
        } 
    },
})
```

Apex :

```
public with sharing class samplePagerCtrl {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static AccountPagerWrapper fetchAccount(Decimal pageNumber ,Integer recordToDisply) {
        Integer pageSize = recordToDisply;
        Integer offset = ((Integer)pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

        // create a instance of wrapper class.
        AccountPagerWrapper obj =  new AccountPagerWrapper();
        // set the pageSize,Page(Number), total records and accounts List(using OFFSET)   
        obj.pageSize = pageSize;
        obj.page = (Integer) pageNumber;
        obj.total = [SELECT count() FROM account];
        obj.accounts = [SELECT id, AccountNumber, Name, Industry, Type,
                       (SELECT Id,Account.name, Name, Phone,MailingCity,MailingCountry FROM Contacts),
                       (SELECT Id,Account.name,Name,StageName,CloseDate,Probability FROM Opportunities)  
                        FROM Account ORDER BY Name LIMIT :recordToDisply OFFSET :offset];
        //obj.contacts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact where Account.Id = '' ORDER BY Name LIMIT:5  ];
        // return the wrapper class instance .
        return obj;
    }

    // create a wrapper class with @AuraEnabled Properties    
    public class AccountPagerWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled public Integer pageSize {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer page {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer total {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public List<Account> accounts{get;set;}
      //@AuraEnabled public List<Contact> contacts{get;set;}

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? There's a bunch of code provided but no description of what the actual issue is.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because it's answerable and tsalb has provided the answer, but it's unclear because far too much code is included. Only the Lightning component markup, the handler `sectionOne`, and the helper function `helperFun` are relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Aura:id inside iterations are not unique. By design, it's assigned to each element so you're targeting them all.

You'll need to either componentize each row, so a `c:rowComponent` and have itself handle the expansion, or you can leverage `class` or `name` or if you're using an HTML element, a custom HTML attribute (e.g. `data-id`) to create a unique identifier.

Something like:

`name="{! v.recordId +'_myCustomRow_'+ v.index }"`

Which gets you a nice unique concat.